# How do i open all files of the format "test*.txt" in golang

Tags: regex, go, unix, grep, go-flag

If I give a flag (in golang) as 'test*.txt' (as a CLI argument), I need to open all files of the said format (example: test.txt, test1.txt, test2.txt).

I am thinking of doing a regex match with all the files present in the folder. Is there a better way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [filepath.Glob](https://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob) function:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "path/filepath"
)

func main() {
    matches, _ := filepath.Glob("test*.txt")
    for _, p := range matches {
        fmt.Println(p)
    }
}
```